# How can I install a new "version" of my app without replacing the old?

Tags: ios

How can I install a new "version" of my app/project on my iPhone without replacing the old app?  Is there an non-intrusive and simple way to make the iPhone think it is another app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it another app by changing the bundle id. You can't have 2 versions of the same app (same bundle id but different version number).

Comment: Also note that users won't be able to update to it. You will need to make a new app under iTunes connect AND most importantly your users will need to rebuy the app.

Comment: @Sirens If I change the bundle ID back to the original before submission it will not be a problem right?

Comment: Yes, this should just be done temporarily for testing, the bundle id will need to be reset before submission.